# How to call Python scripts in Java and pass an ArrayList into it to process?

Tags: python, java, android-studio

Is there an example of how to pass an Integer ArrayList from Java into a Python script for processing, and then retrieve a string result back from the Python script into the Java code again?

Also, is it possible to put the python script in an android studio project?

*Note: the python script contains the usage of SymPy library...

Answer (score 0):

Export to JSON then import from JSON.

```
import json

def fromjson(data):
    return json.loads(data)

x = fromjson('{"test":"value"}')
print(type(x))
```